# biblatex: space after modified bibnamedash when followed by "ed."

Tags: spacing, biblatex

I have run into a problem concerning spacing after bibnamedash and was hoping to find help here.

I have modified `\bibnamedash` with `\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{\rule[3pt]{3em}{.6pt}}` to get a `3-em` dash, which works fine in general, but when the dash is followed by "`ed.`", the space between the dash and "`ed`." is missing. I attach a minimal runnable example below. Is this a bug? Is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@incollection{Elster1997,
author = {Elster, Jon},
title = {The market and the forum},
subtitle = {Three varieties of political theory},
editor = {Bohman, James and Rehg, William},
location = {Cambridge, Massachusetts},
publisher = {The MIT Press},
year = {1997},
booktitle = {Deliberative democracy},
booksubtitle = {Essays on reason and politics},
pages = {3-33},
}
@collection{Elster1998,
editor = {Elster, Jon},
title = {Deliberative democracy},
location = {Cambridge},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
year = {1998},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{\rule[3pt]{3em}{.6pt}}

\addbibresource{biblio.bib}


\begin{document}

This is a test file for biblatex (\cite{Elster1997}; \cite{Elster1998}).

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Use `\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{\rule[3pt]{3em}{.6pt}\space}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Or, possibly better, `\addspace`

Comment: @egreg: I thought the same but please see my answer. I also found this post where P. Lehmann doesn't  complain about `\space`: http://www.digipedia.pl/usenet/thread/1902/35231/ ;-)

Comment: Instead of posting a “Thank you” as an additional answer, you should thank [user] by upvoting [his/her] answer (with the upward pointing arrow to the left of it; you need 15 reputation points before you can upvote) and accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark). We want to keep the answer space reserved for actual answers, so this non-answer will be removed from public view soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default definition of `bibnamedash` is more complex. You can find the definition in the file `biblatex.def`. To explain the solution here the definition:

```
\newcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
  \ifdimless{\leftmargin}{0.75em}
    {\mbox{\textemdash\space}}
    {\makebox[\leftmargin][l]{%
       \ifdimless{\leftmargin}{1.25em}
         {\textendash}
     {\textemdash}}}}
```

You can see, that the width of `bibnamedash` is related to `leftmargin` whereby the simple definition is: `\mbox{\textemdash\space}`. The other part can be ignored here. So for your problem you can easily do:

```
\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{\rule[3pt]{3em}{.6pt}\space}
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use a length based on `ex` units for the rule's height: `\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{\rule[0.58ex]{3em}{.4pt}\space}`. In this way the command is independent on the point size; 0.6pt seems too thick, but it's a matter of taste. The `\mbox` is surely redundant.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the immediate reply! I have one more question, though: I realize that, according to the Chicago Manual of Style, which I am trying to follow here, the 3-em dash should in such cases be followed by a comma and then a space (since the dash stands for the name of the author/editor, and the name is followed by a comma when followed by "ed."). So how can I add a comma to the dash when the dash is followed by "ed."?

Comment: @egreg: Is the mbox redundant? I think you are right.The dimension `ex` is recommended depends on the author ;-)

Comment: @Wolfhart: Do you mean `\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{\rule[3pt]{3em}{.6pt}\addcoma\space}`

Comment: @Marco Daniel: The comma should be added after the dash only when followed by "ed.", since only in this case is the name followed by a comma. The command you propose adds the comma in every case. (Also, there is a typo, a missing "m" in addcomma.)

Comment: @Wolfhart: Please try: `\renewcommand{\bibnamedash}{\rule[3pt]{2em}{.6pt}\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\addcomma\space #1}`

Comment: @Marco Daniel: Yes, that's it (except that I had to change "2em" back to "3em"). Many thanks!